# Reusing same models and its set of associations based on selected timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

In Rails 6 application focusing on school management system, I am looking for a way by which a structure created by any school can be reused again, for every academic year.

Xaviers School - academic year 2022

- has_many :classrooms (class 1A..1C,...till class 10A...10C)

  - has_many :albums (Exam day, First day, Science fair, Sports Day ...etc)
  - has_many :tutors (Mr.Json, Mrs Smith...etc)
  - has_many :students

if the above structure of models is created by the a School for 2022.For the next upcoming year 2023, Can they reuse the structure for 2022?
How can do this without recreating every model and its association for 2023 as well, assuming I have added a new relationship of organization belongs_to org_year(2021, 2022, 2023...and so on), because **Class A for year 2023 will be different for same Class A for year 2022 but the albums still will be the same irrespective of the year.**

How to achieve this?

I wanted to try [papertrail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail), but this will be an overkill.

My solution - if I add a `belongs_to :academic_year` for organzation/school model, then, I can get all the data for a specified academic year and then will regenerate everything by hitting explicit insert queries.

```
old_school_structure = AcademicYear.get_school_data("2022")
// regenerate new set for new year
new_school_structure = AcademicYear.set_school_data("2023")
```

Can use [ActiveRecord::Base#clone](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/clone) and https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable,
But, not sure this will work on large data sets with large associations for large schools with large number of classrooms and albums.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a similar app, we had a script that created a new year and copied the previous year's structure over to the new year. We never wanted to just use the previous year because we wanted to maintain the history of what happened in previous years (at least for a few years).

We also actually moved the students to the next year too, even though this was occasionally false (a kid repeating a year), it was mostly the case and it was much easier for teachers/admins to move a few kids back than all the rest forward.

I don't remember if we used `clone`, but we certainly didn't use any deep clone, we didn't have that many layers and it was fairly simple to just iterate down through them.